# How fast is the GoPro Supercharger?

Tags: gopro

How many minutes/hours does it take to charge a 0% GoPro Hero 5 to 100%?

Searched Google but got no answer at all. Any tips on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all to be found on the [GoPro web page](https://gopro.com/help/articles/How_To/How-to-Charge-Your-HERO5-Black):

> From a completely depleted battery, it can take about 2 hours using a
>   USB wall charger ... The Supercharger allows the camera to charge up
>   to 20% faster.

'Up to 20% faster than about 2 hours' is of course still pretty vague, but at least 1 hour, 40 minutes. In reality, you should probably expect around 2 hours.

Comment: 20% faster is really not a `super` stuff.... lol. Thanks very much for your help.